# Trusted Root Code Signing Certificates with Whois Privacy Protection

Tags: c#, clickonce, signing, whois, smartscreen

I understand that I have to purchase a code signing certificate from a trusted CA and sign my application to pass the Smartscreen filter in Windows.

On the otherhand I want to protect my privacy like I do for my domain with Whois Privacy Protection enabled.

So my question is.

Are there any Trusted Root Certification Authorities where I can buy a code signing certificate with Whois Privacy Protection enabled?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think Whois Privacy Protection option is from your domain name registrator.

Comment: Yes. I asked for a similar concept in the code signing world. lets call it "Trusted Root Certificate with protection of personal data and privacy"